# How to make Choropleth map using Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, choropleth

I want to make **Choropleth** map in Openlayers 3 which is already implemented in [*Leaflet*](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) but not in Openlayers 3. how to integrate 'colorbrewer' in Openlayers 3?
Give the working example of it.

Comment: You can do it using GEOJSON, provide density in geojson in open layers

Comment: Have some look on this link http://thematicmapping.org/playground/javascript/openlayers_choropleth_geojson.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use this thematic mapping api which provides choropleth using open layers using GEOJSON and KML both.

Please have a look on this api

[Themetic mapping API](http://thematicmapping.org/playground/openlayers_choropleth_kml.php)

There is also another API which provides live demo [here](http://dev.mapfish.org/sandbox/website/.build/html/examples.html)

[Map Fish API](http://demo.mapfish.org/openexpo/examples/geostat/choropleths.html)

[openlayers 2](http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/307/choropleth-maps-with-openlayers-26/) is working but for openlayers 3 there is still search in progress. Dynamic sld is one option with open layers 3.

Comment: Themetic mapping API is used with Openlayers 2 only. It does not support Openlayers 3.

Comment: But you can also make dynamic sld with openlayers 3

Comment: That works if style attribute is in shape file which should be published in map server. But if our style attribute is in outside database(not in shape file) then this technique will not work. for example, I want to make population categorized map. But if that population data is not in shape file, how to colorize map on population basis.

Comment: That is different question/case.There is an example in geoserver that shows population of usa. That kind of maps can be generated using geoserver. For the case of reading attribute see this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71986/geoserver-sld-size-by-scale-and-color-by-attribute and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373628/how-to-fill-color-in-sld-with-the-features-attribute